# Compiler error using arm-none-eabi-gcc and bool variables

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32

I am trying to compile a usb loopback example for STM32 using arm-none-eabi-gcc but am stuck on a compiler error for bool variables. The error is `error: expected ';', identifier or '(' before '_Bool'` and the offending lines are

```
typedef enum
{
  FALSE = 0, TRUE  = !FALSE
}
bool;
```

From what I've read, it seems `bool` is an alias for `_Bool` while gcc transitions to `bool` being an actual type. Unfortunately I have no idea how to fix this. With some googling I've read that similar problems are sometimes related to having `TRUE` and `FALSE` defined elsewhere but I'm using largely unchanged code from STM and don't know of anywhere else they might be defined. I've also read that it could be due to linking against libc but get the same error when compiling with `-nostdlib`. Is there anything I can do to narrow down this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you compiling as C99 (either with `-std=...` or just from your compiler's default configuration)? `_Bool` is the C99 (and previously GNU89 extension) boolean type, `bool` is a macro specified by the standard to be defined in `<stdbool.h>`, along with `true` and `false` (note lowercase).

Comment: It is highly likely that you are not in C99 mode. C doesn't got a standard bool type. C99 has _Bool. Try including stdbool.h if your toolchain supports that.

Comment: I actually did try including `<stdbool.h>` in the file where the typedef was, but still get the same error. I also just tried `-std=c99` and still get the same error. I'm not sure how to check whether the toolchain supports stdbool.h but I didn't get any error when I included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this typedef was trying to define a bool type and my compiler was trying to use the _Bool type, what I ended up doing was commenting out the typedef all together and just using

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

I'm not positive this solved the problem since I still can't get the usb device to enumerate, but the program now compiles.